# how can I fix this error in this code? index out of range

Tags: python

I have a function that let me put any string and return me the high value alphabetically. For instance, if I have a sentence like "Hello world" and we supposed that `world` is bigger than `hello` then we will return `world`.

This high value is measured by index I set before in `string_index_in_char`.

```
def func(string):
    char = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    split_string = string.split()
    i = 0
    x = ""

    # get letters
    string = string.lower()
    for s in string:
        if s in char:
            string_index_in_char = char.index(s) + 1
        else:
            string_index_in_char = 0
        x += str(string_index_in_char)
        split_any_char_not_letters = x.split("0")
    # convert string into interger in list  
    for i in range(0, len(split_any_char_not_letters)): 
        split_any_char_not_letters[i] = int(split_any_char_not_letters[i])      
    convert_to_int = split_any_char_not_letters 

    # (split_string, convert_to_int) comparison
    n = convert_to_int.index(max(convert_to_int))
    my_string = split_string[n]
    print("%s -> %s" %(string, my_string.lower()))


#func("This Is my home")
func("Hello wOrld")
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\courses\udacity-python\python\Exam\alphabet\alphabet 5.py", line 27, in <module>
    func("This Is my home")
  File "D:\courses\udacity-python\python\Exam\alphabet\alphabet 5.py", line 23, in func
    my_string = split_string[n]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

No problem appears with me just when I type any other words like `"man i need a taxi up to Ubud"` or some words. So why it get this error despite it not sending me this error when I type "hello world"?

Comment: Can you add the full error trace?

Comment: I modified my post you will see the trace below of the code but if I typed any word other than "hello world" like "this is my home" that I hashed in my code I will get this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated as suggested by @Parakiwi:
The problem occurs when you split the `zero`, in your example: this is my home, t is at position `20` since you split by `0` it affects the code by adding extra value to the split list causing the error. Changing to any arbitrary number apart from those of char index like `<<carefully chosen split criteria>>` will work:

Change:

```
if s in char:
    string_index_in_char = char.index(s) + 1
    print(string_index_in_char)
else:
    string_index_in_char = "^"
x += str(string_index_in_char)
split_any_char_not_letters = x.split("^")
```

Before:

```
if s in char:
            string_index_in_char = char.index(s) + 1
        else:
            string_index_in_char = 0
        x += str(string_index_in_char)
        split_any_char_not_letters = x.split("0")
```

However, you would need to handle the case of an equality of two words.

Comment: Be careful with your choice of arbitrary number. The snippet "can i eat" would evaluate to "311399999995120" which might cause you issues when splitting by the string "999" later on.  Also, "999" would be possible if the text had some for of the letter "i" three times, such as a roman numeral value for 3, so "James III of scotland" would cause you an issue.

Comment: @Parakiwi, thank will update the answer with the removal of the number - 999

Comment: You could simply use comma as your delimiter by adding a "," and splitting by it again later? This would save confusion with numbers and letters

Comment: @Parakiwi I think there can be a comma as well in a sentence i suppose, so will add a special character `^` for an updated answer

Comment: I feel some confusion in understanding
In your words, what do you mean carefully (chosen number)?
sorry I have a confused, could you explain further

Comment: it works but I have no idea why you used caret sign could you explain that

Comment: @abdelhamed you were using 0 to split causing problem, so instead use special characters rather than by a number which is split criteria. I have updated the answer .